# RequestError: RequestError(400, search_phase_execution_exception failed to create query For input string in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

Below is my dictionary

```
abc = [
{'id':"1",  'name': 'cristiano ronaldo', 'description': 'portugal@fifa.com'},
{'id':"2",  'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'argentina@fifa.com'},
{'id':"3",  'name': 'Lionel Jr', 'description': 'brazil@fifa.com'}
]
```

Ingested the players into elasticsearch

```
for i in abc:
    es.index(index="players", body=i, id=i['id'])
```

Below is the dsl query

```
resp = es.search(index="players",body={
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "fields": ["id^12","description^2", "name^2"], 
      "query": "brazil@fifa.com"
    }
  }})
resp
```

- Issue 1:
  if `"fields": ["id^12","description^2", "name^2"]` then i am getting error `RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: For input string: "brazil@fifa.com"'`
- Issue 2:
  if my fields are `["description^2", "name^2"]` I am expecting one document which contain  `brazil@fifa.com` but returning all 3 documents

Edited: From the comment of sagar my setting id was long which i changed now . mapping is below.  and **issue1** is resolved

```
{'players': {'mappings': {'properties': {'description': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}},
    'id': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}},
    'name': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Can you please share index mapping ? is it your `id` field define as int or flot in index mapping ?

Comment: I changed the mappings, id to text, now issue1 is resolved {'players': {'mappings': {'properties': {'description': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}},
    'id': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}},
    'name': {'type': 'text',
     'fields': {'keyword': {'type': 'keyword', 'ignore_above': 256}}}}}}}

Comment: Thanks for providing mapping. Please check below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue 1: if "fields": ["id^12","description^2", "name^2"] then i am
> getting error RequestError: RequestError(400,
> 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: For input
> string: "brazil@fifa.com"'

Above issue you are getting because your `id` field is define as `integer` or `flot` type of field (other then `text` type of field). You need to provide `"lenient": true` in your query and it will not return any exception.

> Issue 2: if my fields are ["description^2", "name^2"] I am expecting
> one document which contain brazil@fifa.com but returning all 3
> documents

Above issue is happening because you are searching on `text` type of field which applied default `standard` analyzer when you do search.

So when you search `brazil@fifa.com` then it will create two token `brazil` and `fifa.com`. Here, `fifa.com` is matching in your all 3 documents so it is returning in result. To resolved this issue, you can use `description.keyword` field.

Below query will resolved your both issue:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "lenient": true, 
      "fields": [
        "id^12",
        "description.keyword^2",
        "name^2"
      ],
      "query": "brazil@fifa.com"
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated:**

Based on comment if you want to search `fifa` as well then you need to provide `description` as field but when you search `brazil@fifa.com` then you need to provide it in double quotes for exact match. Please see below example:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "lenient": true, 
      "fields": [
        "id^12",
        "description^2",
        "name^2"
      ],
      "query": "\"brazil@fifa.com\""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: will it impact any other search like if i am searching `fifa` in the query, will it cause any issue. Like latency issue anything like that

Comment: also can you share elastic doc saying this for the second issue?

Comment: Yes, it will impact because once you provide field as `description.keyword` and search for `fifa` it will not return any response. Please check my updated answer for how you can do extact match with `description` field.

Comment: Hey got it sagar, any latency issue will be there ,if we put description.keyword instead of description  which i want to know

Comment: it not impact latency but you need to do testing of it with your data. jsut thing you need to note is `description.keyword` will do exact match and not allowed partial match.